# Dependence of a r.v. $Z_{i,j} = X_{i} + Y_{j}$ with $X$ and $Y$ independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, correlation

Say we draw a random sample of size $N$ of iid rv $X$ and a random sample of iid rv $Y$. What is the level of dependence (say. measured by Pearson's correlation) of a random variable $Z_{k} = Z_{i,j} = X_{i} + Y_{j}$ with  $i=1..N$ and $j=1..M$, $k=M\cdot N$ and $k=(i-1)\cdot M+j$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent? What would be the distribution of $Z$ if, say, $X$ and $Y$ were sampled from a normal distribution? (I assume that $Z$ constructed in this way are not independent, right?)

My feeling is that $\mathsf{Corr}(Z_{i,j},Z_{k,l})= P(i = k) + P(j = l) = \frac{1}{N} +\frac{1}{M} $ but I am not sure if this is correct and how to prove it.

**Added after comments**

In the above I assume that $$\mathsf{Corr}(Z_{i,j},Z_{k,l}) = \mathsf{Corr}(Z_{i,j},Z_{i,l})\cdot P(X_i=X_k) + \mathsf{Corr}(Z_{i,j},Z_{k,j})\cdot P(Y_j=Y_l)+ \mathsf{Corr}(Z_{i,j},Z_{k,l})\cdot P(Y_j \neq Y_l  \; and \;  X_i \neq X_k)$$

with $\mathsf{Corr}(Z_{i,j},Z_{i,l}) = \mathsf{Corr}(Z_{i,j},Z_{k,j}) = 1$, but I am not sure if one can decompose correlation in that way. I might be missing the cross term in the above, i.e. the one corresponding to $P(Y_j = Y_l  \; and \;  X_i = X_k)$.

Comment: I don't understand.  $i, k, j, l$ are not random variables, they are particular indices.  There is no such thing as $P(i=k)$ or $P(j=\ell)$.

Comment: Maybe it was too much of an abuse of notation. What I should have probably written is $P(X_{i} = X_{k})$ and $P(Y_{j} = Y_{l})$.Thanks

Comment: So e.g. $Z_{1,2}$ and $Z_{3,4}$ are independent, but $Z_{1,2}$ and $Z_{1,3}$ are not.  The covariance of $Z_{1,2}$ and $Z_{1,3}$ is the variance of $X$.

Comment: Yes. I believe that's right. But what about $Z$ overall?

Comment: Overall, you have a multivariate distribution with a certain covariance matrix.  If $X$ and $Y$ are normal it will be multivariate normal.

Comment: Multivariate? Why? $Z$ is the SUM of two RVs. In the "usual" case where $Z_{i} = X_{i} + Y_{i}$  $Z$ would be simple normal (with appropriate mean and variance).

Comment: By "overall" I assumed you meant the collection of all the $Z_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1):

When $i,j,k,l$ are mutually distinct indices, $X_i, Y_j, X_k, Y_l$ are mutually independent random variables and thus $Z_{i,j},Z_{k,l}$ are uncorrelated.†   So, as you said: $$\mathsf{Corr}(Z_{i,j}, Z_{k,l})=0$$

(† $\tiny\text{you can show this by the bilinearity of covariance: } \mathsf{Cov}(U+V,X+Y)=\mathsf{Cov}(U,X)+\mathsf{Cov}(U,Y)+\mathsf{Cov}(V,X)+\mathsf{Cov}(V,Y)$)

Because $X_h\perp Y_h$ (independence between the samples), therefore you can also demonstrate : $$\begin{align}0 & = \mathsf {Corr}(Z_{i,j},Z_{k,i})\\ &=\mathsf {Corr}(Z_{i,j},Z_{j,l})\\&=\mathsf {Corr}(Z_{i,j},Z_{j,i})\end{align}$$

Consider now $Z_{i,j},Z_{k,j}$ using the Bilinearity of Covariance, the identical distribution *among* each of the two samples, and the independence between them.
$$\begin{align}\mathsf {Corr}(Z_{i,j},Z_{k,j}) & =\dfrac{\mathsf {Cov}(X_i+Y_j,X_k+Y_j)}{\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}(X_i+Y_j)\mathsf{Var}(X_k+Y_j)}}\\[2ex]& = \end{align}$$

And similarly you have $\mathsf {Corr}(Z_{i,j},Z_{i,l})$

Finally, is $\mathsf {Corr}(Z_{i,j},Z_{i,j})$ not obvious?

Comment: Yes, that's all clear. What I am looking for is a correlation between any two randomly drawn $Z$, not restricting to any specific permutation of indices. And the distribution function for $Z$ in a case $X$ and $Y$ are from a normal distribution. Thanks